# clipboard accessing data in format

Tags: c#

I am doing a copy-paste for the syncfusion grid control.

My question is more abt the paste than abt syncfusion

My data is in datetime-int, datetime-int... format, depending on number of rows,columns selected. 
Here's my code to for the paste

```
private void theGrid_ClipboardPaste(object sender, GridCutPasteEventArgs e)
        {
 DataObject data = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
  try
            {

                if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                {
 rowsInClipboard =  stringInClipboard.Split('\n');
                    //split into cellvalues
                     for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rowsInClipboard.Length; iRow++)
                         ValuesInrows = rowsInClipboard[iRow].Split('\t');
...}
```

How would I validate this data being pasted from the clipboard to the grid. Would it help if I did a custom format. 
Also I need access the clipboard data based on columns.

Thanks 
Sun

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the clipboard data while pasting to grid through event ClipboardCanPaste.

```
this.gridControl1.ClipboardCanPaste += new GridCutPasteEventHandler(gridControl1_ClipboardCanPaste); //get triggered before pasting occurs.
```

If you would like to access the clipboard data to paste to grid across columns, you can split the respective values through a tab key press space in between each illustrating individual cell contents. The following code copies the cell contents across grid cells in the formatted manner to clipboard inorder to make use of this formatted text while pasting from clipboard to any text editor in the column order.

```
private void CopyCellsToClipboard(GridRangeInfo range)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = range.Top; i <= range.Bottom; i++)
{
for (int j = range.Left; j <= range.Right; j++)
{
if (! (this.gridControl1.Cols.Hidden[j]))
{
sb.Append(this.gridControl1[i, j].FormattedText);
sb.Append("\t");
}
}
sb.AppendLine(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
string str = sb.ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine);
DataObject db = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, str);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(db);
}
```